# How to scroll automatically StyledText (SWT)

Tags: scroll, swt, scrollbar, styledtext

I have a StyledText widget with both scrollbars. 
The text inside is bigger than the client area (both scrollbars are active). 
I iterate through every char from the text.

How to scroll automatically in order to show every char visible (char selected by iterator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `showSelection` method of `StyledText` to make sure the current selection is visible.